# Motion save to usb hdd - no permissions

Tags: raspbian, usb, headless, permissions, motion

I'm wanting to use my Pi as a dashboard camera and I'm wanting motion to save its files to the usb but it doesn't have permissions to save to it.  The usb is currently FAT32 so I can plug it into a Windows PC and see the files.  If making it ext4 will fix this I'll do it.  The motion daemon needs to have access to the usb without a user logging in as the Pi will be headless.  I have tried setting user to **nobody** in the permissions but I get **Operation not permitted** errors, even running as root user.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the mount options when mounting the stick to allow the motion user to write to the USB stick.
Try these fstab options
`/dev/sda1 /opt/yourmountpoint vfat -o umask=000 0 0`

Comment: Did everything except for the **-o** and it works great. Mounted it to /media/USBNAME but had to create the directory there first